# Using photon in Leaflet code: example?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I need to put a geocoder in a Leaflet page and I'd like to uso Photon (rif. http://photon.komoot.de/).

There is a leaflet plugin here https://github.com/komoot/leaflet.photon but no example is given: is there someone that use it in some projects and can give me a little example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you look on the demo source http://photon.komoot.de (Right click > Show source or Ctrl + u with the keyboard)?

I've done a minimum example below just to try and it works

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Photon, search-as-you-type with OpenStreetMap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://photon.komoot.de/static/leaflet.photon/leaflet.photon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://photon.komoot.de/static/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="http://photon.komoot.de/static/leaflet.photon/leaflet.photon.js"></script>
<script src="http://photon.komoot.de/static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For fair use, download each file on your own server and never link directly to those remote files: it's only for the demo purpose.